# How do I stop my nodejs server for test purposes?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, signals, nodejs-server

my nodejs module starts a server on a specific port, I am wondering if it is a way to stop the execution of that server in my mocha test:

Let's assume that myserver.js contains something like:

```
myserver = http.Server(app);
....
process.on('SIGTERM', ()=>{ ... });
```

and in my mocha test, If I do something like this: in order to load my class:

```
   it(' starts the execution and then stop the server() {
     require('../myserver.js');

     ????
    }
```

How can I stop the execution from test case?
I was wondering if I could send a SIGTERM message to that process, but I should discover the pid of that process first, maybe it is not worth to do that.

I assume that I could export from my module a function that is then used from other modules in some specific circumstances, like the one I want to test, in order to stop the overall execution.

Comment: Use the `child_process` module and kill the child process or send a custom signal to it.

Comment: You can also use `fork` to start a new process and then you can kill the process with `SIGKILL` signal.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to send the command a SIGTERM signal, you need to handle that with the process signal handler:

> Note: `process` does not require a “require”, it’s automatically available.

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi!')
});

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'));

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Process terminated');
  });
});
```

> What are signals? Signals are a POSIX intercommunication system: a notification sent to a process in order to notify it of an event that occurred.

`SIGKILL` is the signals that tells a process to immediately terminate, and would ideally act like `process.exit()`.

`SIGTERM` is the signals that tells a process to gracefully terminate. It is the signal that’s sent from process managers like `upstart` or `supervisord` and many others.

You can send this signal from inside the program, in another function:

```js
process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
```

Or from another Node.js running program, or any other app running in your system that knows the PID of the process you want to terminate.

Comment: I agree with you, but the problem is to understand how to recover the pid of the server class, in order to send a sigterm to another loaded module, in this case the server class from my mocha test suite.
I think that this is the approach if I don't export any function that helps me to close the server